# Cant install libsdl2-dev or cmake glfw.. (libxinerama-dev problem)

Tags: apt, dependencies

So I was going to continue learning Opengl after switching to Ubuntu,
I tried this explanation to compile glfw and use it, but I got this:

```
-- Using X11 for window creation
-- Using GLX for context creation
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:268 (message):
  The Xinerama library and headers were not found


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

This is the [*CMakeError.log*](http://pastebin.com/r33hD1ZH) and this is the [CMakeOutput.log](http://pastebin.com/vFdVjDWF).

Ok, after failing at glfw, I moved on to libsdl2:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev
```

And the result (shocking..):

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsdl2-dev : Depends: libxinerama-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What can I do?
I tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install libxinerama-dev
```

The result I get is this:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libxinerama-dev : Depends: libxinerama1 (= 2:1.1.3-1) but 2:1.1.3-1+b1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have software that is installed form source or from a PPA that might be causing the [binNMU](https://wiki.debian.org/binNMU) package to be requested?

Comment: @steeldriver don't think I do.  How can I check that?

Comment: @steeldriver I have installed amd driver from this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD), this is the only thing I have downloaded not using apt-get.. What should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I also ran into same problem while installing the `glfw` lib. This is how I solved it:

1. I navigated into my home directory using:

   ```
   cd ~
   ```
2. I then ran:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libxinerama-dev
   ```
3. I navigated again to the directory of `glfw` and ran:

   ```
   cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"
   ```
4. This time the error was `xcursor lib not found`. So I repeated the above steps and installed the `xcursor` lib with:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libxcursor-dev
   ```
5. After this I navigated back to the `glfw`  directory and the `cmake` command was successful.